# Remove abstract from elsevier class

Tags: templates, abstract

I am using the `elsevier` class to prepare a document.
I would like to remove the abstract environment but I can not find the way to do that. I commented out `\begin{abstract} .... \end{abstract}` but I still get the two horizontal lines
which enclose the abstract.

Comment: Are you intending to send this to a journal, or is it for something else?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268988/latex-remove-abstract-from-article-class?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 8):

As of Feb. 2015, I found that the answer from egreg did not remove the `\hrule`s. There is an additional macro, `\pprintMaketitle` in which I had to comment out the same lines of code to remove the horizontal rules around the abstract that are present even if no abstract is present.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\makeatletter
  \long\def\pprintMaketitle{\clearpage
  \iflongmktitle\if@twocolumn\let\columnwidth=\textwidth\fi\fi
  \resetTitleCounters
  \def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \printFirstPageNotes
  \begin{center}%
 \thispagestyle{pprintTitle}%
   \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \Large\@title\par\vskip18pt
    \normalsize\elsauthors\par\vskip10pt
    \footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt
    % \hrule\vskip12pt
    % \ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    % \ifvoid\keybox\else\unvbox\keybox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    % \hrule\vskip12pt
    \end{center}%
  \gdef\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title}
\author{Author A. Author\corref{cor1}}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding Author}
\ead{author@example.com}
\address{Department of Studies, Anywhere U}
\end{frontmatter}

This is the body text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about for `[final]`? this solution only seems to work for `[preprint]`.

Comment: not working for me for `[preprint]`

Answer (score 7):

The two rules are hardcoded in `\MaketitleBox`, so you have to patch it:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\MaketitleBox{%
  \resetTitleCounters
  \def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \begin{center}%
   \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \Large\@title\par\vskip18pt
    \normalsize\elsauthors\par\vskip10pt
    \footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt
%    \hrule\vskip12pt
%    \ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip10pt\fi
%    \ifvoid\keybox\else\unvbox\keybox\par\vskip10pt\fi
%    \hrule\vskip12pt
    \end{center}%
  }
\makeatother
```

This code should go into your preamble. I assumed it's `elsarticle.cls` that you're talking about, as I don't know of a `elsevier.cls`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in the new version (2019), and as pointed out by egreg and darthbith, this is indeed hardcoded in **elsearticle.cls** and needs to be patched yourself. However, this alone did not fix the issue anymore. Instead, the following code **also** has to be appropriately commented in the **ecrc.sty** file (now also present in the template) to completely remove them. Hope this helps for new readers.

```
\long\def\MaketitleBox{%
  \resetTitleCounters
  \def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \begin{center}%
  \ifx\@dochead\@empty\relax%
     \vspace*{3pc}%
  \else%
     \vspace*{5pc}%
   \@dochead%
     \par%
     \vspace*{1.75pc}%
   \fi%
   \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    {\strut\elsarticle@titlefont\@title\strut}\par\vskip18pt
%   \normalsize\elsauthors\par\vskip10pt
    {\elsarticle@authorfont\elsauthors}\par\vskip10pt
    {\elsarticle@supervisorsfont\elssupervisors}\par\vskip12pt
    \footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip6pt
    % \hrule\vskip12pt
    % \ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    % \ifvoid\keybox\else\unvbox\keybox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    % \hrule\vskip2pt
    \end{center}%
   \ifcase\jtype\or
    \vspace*{-20pt}%
   \or 
   \or 
    \vspace*{-20pt}%
   \fi 
}
```