# How to remove two lines around blank abstract in Elsevier final output?

Tags: rules, abstract, elsarticle, front-matter

I'm using `\documentclass[final]{elsarticle}` to prepare supplementary materials for a paper I'll be submitting to an Elsevier journal. Obviously there is no need for an abstract here, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the two horizontal lines:

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
        \title{This is the paper you are looking for}
        \author[]{O. Kenobi}
    \end{frontmatter}
    \lipsum[8]
\end{document}
```

---

There are at least two related questions addressing this problem for `\documentclass`**`[preprint]`**`{elsarticle}`, but those solutions don't work for **`[final]`**:

- [How to get rid of the two lines for empty abstract and keyword sections?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245838/106655)
- [Remove abstract from elsevier class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36140/106655)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules are hard-coded in the construction of the title and remain there even if no abstract or keywords are provided. Removing them is best done using a redefinition of `\MaketitleBox` (or using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patching):

[image]

```
\documentclass[final,3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\MaketitleBox}{%
  \resetTitleCounters
  \def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \begin{center}
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \Large \@title \par
    \vskip 18pt
    \normalsize\elsauthors \par
    \vskip 10pt
    \footnotesize \itshape \elsaddress \par
  \end{center}
  \vskip 12pt
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{This is the paper you are looking for}
\author{O. Kenobi}
\end{frontmatter}

\lipsum[8]

\end{document}
```

The redefinition is actually just grabbing everything from the original `\MaketitleBox` up to where the rules are usually inserted. You can adjust the space below the title to suit your needs.